# Distributed tensorflow where to keep data

Tags: tensorflow, distributed

I am using 3 machines for distributed tensorflow (2 workers and 1 ps). All lie on the same cluster. I have placed my data on worker 1. My model works well but it uses only ps and 1 worker.
My question is how is data placed so that all my workers can access it? Should I place it in shared memory like hdfs?

```js
tf.reset_default_graph()
if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":
    server.join()
elif FLAGS.job_name == "worker":
    # Between-graph replication
    with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter( worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index, cluster=Cluster)):
      ## here defining my model, cost, optimizer

    sv = tf.train.Supervisor(is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index == 0), global_step=global_step, init_op=init_op)
    with sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session(server.target) as sess:
        for epoch in range(training_epochs):
           cost_val = sess.run([ cost ], feed_dict={X: data})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some relevant info here: 
[1][GRPC causes training to pause in individual worker (distributed tensorflow, synchronised)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46322337/grpc-causes-training-to-pause-in-individual-worker-distributed-tensorflow-sync)
Appears that we need to create TFRecords.